# Symfony api showing link instead of object

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using Symfony API platforms to build up a rest API.

[image]

I have created a table named "companies" with some information and another table named "offers" which has field relation many to one (many offers belong to one company).

When I use postman to call my API on offers it shows me the link to related company instead of object itself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you are looking for https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations but it isn't clear from how the question is presented. Images of text aren't searchable or accessible, and can either be augmented with the text they contain or replaced by the text if the image doesn't add important information.

Answer (score 1):

Please show us your `Company`-Entity declaration. You are using custom normalization groups here, so you need to set

```
@Groups({"GROUP_NAME"})
```

to *every* property of `Company` you want to have in the output representation.

Documentation for this: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#normalization